# What is the difference between the tensor product of a covector and a vector and a covector acting on a vector as a 1-form?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

I believe I'm getting quite confused between the tensor product and the dual vector as a 1-form acting on a usual vector. Essentially, I'm struggling to distinguish the difference between $\epsilon^{i}(\vec{e}_{j})$ and $\epsilon^{i}\otimes \vec{e}_{j}$. I know that in the first case, it's a Kronecker delta, while in the second case, it's a basis. My issue arises when constructing a tensor, say $D^{i}\ _{j} \ ^{k}$, which can be expressed in terms of its basis as:

$D = D^{i}\ {j} \ ^{k} (\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}\otimes \vec{e}_{k})$

In what situation does $ \epsilon^{j}\otimes \vec{e}_{k} = \epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{k}) = \delta^{j}_{k}$ hold true? Perhaps my problem lies in understanding the difference (if it exists) between $A(B) = D$, where $A$ and $B$ are tensors, and $A\otimes B = D$.

More precisely, let's assume that $A = A^{i}\ _{jk} \left(\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}\otimes \epsilon^{k}\right)$ and $B = B^{lm}\left(\vec{e}_{l}\otimes \vec{e}_{m}\right)$. Is there a difference between $A(B)$ and $A \otimes B$ in such a way that one of them provides me

$D^{i} = A^{i}\ _{jk} B^{jk} $

and the other provides me, for example,

$D^{i}\ _{j} \ ^{m} = A^{i}\ _{jk} B^{km} $ ?

In the first case, we have for the bases $\epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{l})=\delta^{j}_{l}$ and $\epsilon^{k}(\vec{e}_{m})=\delta^{k}_{m}$, while in the second case, we have $\vec{e}_{i}\otimes \epsilon^{j}\otimes \vec{e}_{m}$ and $\epsilon^{k}(\vec{e}_{l})=\delta^{k}_{l}$. I really can't understand when I have the first case and when I have the second case. Although I can distinguish the difference between the vector in the first case and the third-order tensor in the second case, I can't establish the relationship between $D^{i}$ and $D^{i}\ _{j} \ ^{m}$ mathematically. What changes if I forcibly set $j=m$?

Comment: $\epsilon^{j}\otimes \vec{e}_{k} = \epsilon^{j}(\vec{e}_{k}) = \delta^{j}_{k}
$ is never true. The right hand side is a number (0 or 1) while the left hand side is a tensor (not a number). In fact it is the tensor contraction of the first and second slot applied to the tensor $\epsilon^{j}\otimes \vec{e}_{k}$. You seem to be getting confused between tensors, tensor contractions and the basis components of tensors. In your second example $D^i {}_j {}^m$ are not the components of $A \otimes B$, instead its the components of the contraction of the third and fourth slot of $ A \otimes B$.

Comment: Thank you for the response, so there should be a clear difference between $A(B)$ and $A\times B$, correct?

Comment: Yes, if $V$ is the underlying vector space and $V^*$ the dual space, then $A \in V \otimes V^* \otimes V^*$ and $B \in V \otimes V$ so $A \otimes B \in V \otimes V^* \otimes V^* \otimes  V \otimes V$ and $A(B) \in V$. So the two are objects from totally different vector spaces.

Comment: I am not sure what the comparison to composition and multiplication of two functions would be?

Comment: I'm almost getting it; one thing that isn't clear to me is, for example, in the following scenario: consider two tensors $S^{ij}$ and $T_{k}$; through the tensor product, we have $S^{ij}T_{k}$. Under what circumstances would it be permissible (or in what situation) for me to assume that $k=j$ and perform the contraction $S^{ij}T_{j}=D^{i}$? I understand that the tensor product isn't related to the inner product, but index contraction is perplexing. It seems tensors resulting from the tensor product can't have index contractions; they're distinct operations.

Comment: Yes. Socratic question: Under what circumstances would it be permissible to compute the trace of a matrix? Can you express that in index notation?

Comment: @Amalie Yes, it is allways possible to contract indices that are opposite to each other (one down, one up) to obtain a new tensor of a different type.